# AWS Secrets Manager maximum number of versions for a secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-secrets-manager

I have this scheduled lambda fn that keeps track of a valid Auth Bearer token. It will update secrets manager secret value whenever this token is invalid or about to expire (say once a month).

I'm not using any sort of rotations, just updating the secret value using node sdk `putSecretValue` (also tried it using `updateSecret`).

After having this code in production for a while it started failing with the following:

```
{
  "errorType": "LimitExceededException",
  "errorMessage": "You exceeded the maximum number of versions for a secret (arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:myARN)",
  "trace": [
    "LimitExceededException: You exceeded the maximum number of versions for a secret (arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:myARN)",
```

I have no interest in version tracking, I just want that string to be stored indefinitely until I have to update its value and so forth. Should I be using another solution?

Answer (score 1):

As this is production issue, you can apply following quick workaround till the time your permanent solution is available;

execute AWS CLI `update-secret-version-stage` to deprecate unwanted versions, this will make them eligible to delete by AWS Secrets Manager in the background. You may need to write a small script to execute such a unwanted versions in bulk.

For deprecating a version of a secret, please refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/manage_delete-restore-secret.html#proc-delete-version) document from AWS.

For permanent solution there are several options, some of them are as follows;

1. Using AWS SDK/API calls build logic to [deprecate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/manage_delete-restore-secret.html#proc-delete-version) unwanted versions in your infrastructure or application code.
2. If you have some scheduled automations on production, you can use the same batch/job script used for workaround.
3. Instead of AWS Secrets Manager, switch to use of AWS Systems Manager's [Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) with encrypted value.

Comment: Is there any chance you could help me with the commands? I'm quite lost here and not sure how to deprecate a single version, I've tried a couple commands but it's quite confusing tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Secrets Manager has the concepts of a [staging label](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/terms-concepts.html#term_staging-label) (labels pointing to secret versions) and deprecated version (any version without a staging label). The doc @amitd pointed out (removing a staging label) is needed if you want to deprecate a version that has a label.

However if you are not assigning staging labels to secrets (you can only have 20 anyway), you should not need to remove them. In fact Secrets Manager automatically cleans up all but the last 100 versions of a secret automatically. The error message you describe should only happen if you are creating new versions of a secret faster than they can be cleaned up. If, as you say, they are only being created once a month this should not be happening.

Add logs to your lambda (if not already there) and look at them in cloud watch to see if this is happening more often than expected. You can also check your Cloud Trail logs to look at the calls to Secrets Manager.